# TypeScript Empty object type override other interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I know the type `{}` in TypeScript as "any non-nullish value" following by
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md#default-options

In my understinding follow function type is expected to `func: <T>(arg:T) => T | {}`

```
const func = <T>(arg: T) => {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return arg
    }
    return {}
}
```

but it actually is `const func: <T>(arg: T) => {}`

could you explain why it is not `func: <T>(arg:T) => T | {}` for me?

Comment: Unconstrained generic type parameters still have some vestigial behavior from a time when all types were considered assignable to `{}` and thus `T | {}` gets collapsed to `{}`.  You can either change it to `T extends unknown` [like this](https://tsplay.dev/m3PvyW) or wait until they change this behavior, which looks like it's slated for TS 4.8 (see [ms/TS#49489](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49489), as you can see  [here](https://tsplay.dev/wXQrQN).  If this fully addresses your question I will write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: thank you @jcalz
It wil be fixed with https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-beta/#unconstrained-generics-no-longer-assignable-to